# Unable to access jarfile, `ProcessBuilder`

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to run a jar file from my java program:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "D:\\my.jar"); 
Process p = pb.start();
```

But I am getting this exception:

> Unable to access jarfile D:\my.jar

I am trying this on Windows OS. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you provide complete stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I don't know how I missed it but I was not giving complete name of my jar file:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "D:\\my.1.6.2.jar"); //<----
Process p = pb.start();
```

Anyways its working now. Thanks to all those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Um...use [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) isntead. It will relieve you from too much unnecessary trouble.